# ERROR running force:source:deploy: InvalidPackageDirectory

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, jenkins

Facing below issue in Jenkins Deployment from yesterday(It was working fine till yesterday). Can you please suggest a solution to resolve this issue?

- sfdx force:source:deploy -p ./deploy-sf -l NoTestRun --verbose --loglevel fatal -u testdeploymentusername@test.com

›   Warning: sfdx-cli update available from 7.78.1 to 7.80.0.

Using specified username testdeploymentusername@test.com

**ERROR running force:source:deploy:  InvalidPackageDirectory**

**script returned exit code 1**

The `sfdx-project.json` looks like:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "deploy-sf",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "47.0"
}
```

Comment: sfdx-project.json:
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "path": "deploy-sf",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "47.0"
}

Comment: What's the output from `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log`? There should be a clue to help you there.

Comment: There is an unwanted path "deploy-sf" in sfdx-project.json file, I removed that path and tried deployment, it worked :)

Answer (score 6):

I just got the same error and was puzzled myself as to why it stopped working all of a sudden when I haven't changed the `sfdx-project.json` at all. It turned out that I deleted one of the folders mentioned in the `packageDirectories`.

I'm assuming the same happened to you and you deleted the `deploy-sf` folder without removing it from the `sfdx-project.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the name of directory in `packageDirectories` and actual directory on the disk was slighty different, when I fixed the typo, the error has gone